# Player keeps bumping when walking over to another sprite

Tags: unity, physics

So, my problem is that my play when he walks over to another sprite he will stop.

I fixed that by adding a physics material with 0 density and 0 friction to the player

and adding a circle collider instead of a box collider to the player.

---

However now I have another problem where my character keeps bumping when it enters another sprite.

The sprites are at the exact same height, the objects are just as big and the colliders have the exact size.

I would like to get a fix for this problem, which still allows me to use `Rigidbody2D.AddForce` for movement.

---

**Video of my problem :**

[Video :>](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QvxhVKVbbbI&feature=youtu.be)

---

**How to recreate the problem :**

Make a sprite, add a `Circle Collider 2D` to it and a `Rigidbody2D`.

That will be the player.

Next, make some platforms and add a `Box Collider 2D`

Now, if you let your player walk over the platforms it will (or should..) start bumping.

Comment: I saw your video, but can't replicate the problem. If you have an online repo of your project, I could download it and start it up in Unity.

Comment: @codeepic This happens all the time to me, here's what I do to create my problem : Create a 2D circle collider and attach it to a sprite GameObject with a rigidbody2D, add 3 sprites to your scene, all 3 should have 2D box colliders, make the player walk over them using AddForce, and it should start bumping when the player "crosses" a sprite. Hopefully this made sense.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Plus my design requires some of the object to have box colliders. I am very interested if someone found a real solution that still uses Unity's rigidbodies

Comment: I can see a box collider too on player, larger in height, is it so or I am just confused?

Comment: If it is so, then that is the only problem

Comment: @HamzaHasan It looks like it, but I have checked the size and the Y position of the object and they are exactly the same.

Comment: no no, m talking about the box collider on player

Comment: see [this](http://postimg.org/image/kti5ma0xj/) can you see the box collider? other thn circle collider?

Comment: @HamzaHasan The box colliders are used for grounded checks, they should not effect anything since they are triggers. ? Is that what you meant?

Comment: This is player, and I can see box collider with circle collider, is this box collider trigger??

Comment: @HamzaHasan Yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: Don't build a 2D jump and run using a physics engine. I worked on such a project and we were mostly fighting the physics engine.

Long answer: Have less, bigger colliders. We built our levels using [tiled](http://www.mapeditor.org/). We placed sprites and colliders seperately so one block of floor got only one, big collider. It still has issues at ramps, when falling on the edge of a platform, and so on. There were lots of raycasts and custom forces involved and it was not pretty.

You could also try and merge the colliders / create them on the fly from the sprites, though this is probably more complex.

Comment: Tiled fixed all of the problems! :)

Comment: It doesn't seem like Tiled would work for my purposes considering I am using an in-game level editor. I already tried making my own physics system, but it proved to have more glitches than Unity's, especially with all the force interactions my game requires: push blocks, high-power fans, trampolines, etc. I got it working with Unity's rigidbody physics perfectly except for the occasional catching on corners between blocks. Unless there is a fix, merging colliders may be the only option.